# Shopify form customize fields

Tags: javascript, api, shopify

I have access to the checkout page in Shopify Plus and I need to append a new field into the form. However, when the user adds a new "Discount Code", Shopify make an API request which I have no control of and replaces the form with the fetched data (returned as Html). This causes my new appended element to be removed every time this API request is made.

I have tried listening to DOM changes with MutationObservers but this doesn't do what I'm looking for.

Alternatively, I was thinking if it's possible to check when those API requests made by Shopify have been completed so that I can re-append the form element?

These are the two functions I have to fire in order to append the new form fields via JS:

```
// Append new CHECKBOX
addNewCheckbox({ contactInfo, logged: customerId })

// Update Labels
updateLabels(contactInfo)
```

**Possible solution:**
Checking if the page has any changes with **[MutationObserver](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-tracking-changes-in-the-dom-using-mutationobserver-86adc7446401)**

This way, I can check if the form has been updated and then re-apply my custom fields back into the form

Comment: When you add a form field to checkout form, what exactly is accomplished? You think Shopify does some magic with your field? I am curious what the result is of appending a random field to checkout. Any info appreciated!

Comment: Hi @DavidLazar - So the idea of adding an extra field to Shopify's default forms is because I need to have an extra checkbox so that customer can opt-in/out of 3rd party marketing. Need to have our website GDPR compliant. 

I have noticed that we have 0 control over the forms on the checkout step process, in fact, even when I manage to append an extra field once the form is loaded into the page, it get's removed when the customer uses the "Apply discount" as it makes a new API request and repaints the DOM in those forms.

Comment: Obviously Shopify will not do much with this new field I'm adding, but instead what I do with this field is adding (or not) a customer to a 3rd party mailing list via an API call

Comment: Built in to Shopify, in checkout, is an opt-in/opt-out of marketing. Not sure why you feel the need to add your own.

Comment: Its because in Europe we have new GDPR laws and becuase we also have a "direct mail" (brochure) list then we have to let customers opt-in/out for both email and direct mail marketing.

Comment: Checkout is the wrong place to handle this. Make it obvious, make it work, make it easy to do, make it anywhere on the shop... from the homepage on... trying to jack a square peg in the round hole of checkout is a fool's errand.

Comment: We include these fields in every form in which we take a users email address. So we have it in the footer, registration form, checkout...